# c# Regex to match key value pairs

Tags: c#, regex

Given the following string

```
[ef:id =tellMeMore4, edit= yes, req=true,prompt = false]
```

I'm trying to match the edit key and value where the value can be yes, yesonce or no.

```
edit\s*=\s*(yes(once)?|no)
```

I'm getting back 3 groups:

```
{edit= yes}
{yes}
{}
```

Is there a way to match, meeting my requirements, but not have a group for the optional `once` value?

I tried this but it doesn't match properly on all variances:

```
edit\s*=\s*(yes[once]?|no)
```

Comment: if you are trying to match the edit key, why would you care about what the value is yes or yesonce or no. Your regex should just go on to \w. I would think.

Comment: the values are limited. Only yes, yesonce, or no is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify you don't need to capture a group, use the `(?:` ... `)` construct called a *non-capturing group*:

```
edit\s*=\s*(yes(?:once)?|no)
```

As a rule of thumb, always use the `(?:`...`)` construct instead of `(`...`)` unless you need to capture.

An alternative approach is to use named groups along with the `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` flag:

```
edit\s*=\s*(?<value>yes(once)?|no)
```

And of course, you can combine both approaches so you don't need the flag, but can keep the named capture:

```
edit\s*=\s*(?<value>yes(?:once)?|no)
```

The value is extracted with `match.Groups["value"].Value`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
edit\s*=\s*\b(yesonce|yes|no)\b
```

Also you should use `\b` because you don't want to match `yes` or `yesonce` if the string is `yesoncefunction` .

Comment: `yesonce` should come first. Otherwise, it will match `yes` part of `yesonce`, never matching the full string.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
 edit\s*=\s*(yesonce|yes|no)
```